# Paste into custom GUI with AHK

Tags: user-input, autohotkey, paste

I have been working on this for a while and I have no idea how to fix this issue. I want to create a custom GUI in AutoHotKey (AHK), I would post ont he AHK Forums but I haven't been able to get my account to work so I am posting here (sorry if this is the wrong place). The ideal state is that I can paste in a list of indiscriminate length from a list, it is almost always return delimited, see the picture below. I would be happy with pasting 10 items in. I have built the GUI but I can not paste the values in with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. All that happens is the first value goes into the first cell and I cannot figure out how to get the rest to paste in.

[image: AHK GUI Paste error]
 [image: List of Names]

I need to be able to read the values into an array in the AHK when I click continue. Thanks for your help in advance. Below is my code to create the GUI.

```
Gui, Add, Text,, Please add the List that you want (10 Max at once)

Gui Add, Edit, vButton1,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton2,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton3,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton4,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton5,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton6,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton7,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton8,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton9,
Gui Add, Edit, vButton0,


Gui Add, Button, x200 y270 w88 h26 vButton02 gGoCont, Continue
Gui Add, Button,  x290 y270 w88 h26 vButton03 gGoQuit, Cancel   
Gui Show
return
GoCont:
{

MsgBox %Button1%
MsgBox %Button2%

}
return

GoQuit: 
    Gui Destroy 
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can stand a txt file with one name per line, called "names.txt" in the same folder as your ahk script, try something like this:

Add this to the top (it reads in your names.txt file one line at a time):

```
Loop, Read, names.txt
    x%A_Index% := A_LoopReadLine
```

**START EDIT (per comments):**

Alternatively, if you already copied to the clipboard the several names from a spreadsheet or website table or other list, then put it this way:

```
Loop, parse, Clipboard, `n, `r
    x%A_Index% := A_LoopField
```

Either way,

**END EDIT**

Then, replace all 10 of your edit box lines with these two lines:

```
Loop, 10  ;  or more?
    Gui Add, Edit, vButton%A_Index%, % x%A_Index%
```

The rest is just as you had it.
Let us know,  Have fun,

Comment: That is a good suggestion. It would work for me if I was developing this just for my use. I am trying to develop a tool for my team to use and the majority of my team would not be able to use it well as it would break for them and then be no good. The majority of my team is pretty computer illiterate. Needs to be simpler. Pasting in is the ideal state as it will make this too extremely powerful.

Comment: Don't know what you want.  Do you want to highlight and copy the 10 names, then using a single ctrl+v, paste them in to the ten spots?  So, don't read in the file.  Just read in the clipboard, look for linefeed-carriagereturns and get your pseudo-array ("x1") of names that way.  Then, the rest of my code still works to put it in the textboxes.

Comment: Alrighty, then. See my edited answer for the Clipboard alternative (which may depend on the OS you use -- mine works in Win OSs).  Also, remember to add an application-specific hotkey for Ctrl+v so you can direct it to this script when the user tries to paste.

Comment: Thanks so much your Edits Worked perfectly. I will post my code shortly

Comment: If possible I would like to add a triangle to the side of the box that I am processing in my loop or possibly turn the one that was just processed blue. It will help keep track of place visually. I can't find an easy solution on the web so I thought @PGilm might have a trick with your expertise. If it is picture it would have to move and also be a default windows image that is accessed as this tool is meant to be stand alone.

Comment: Add a triangle where?  To the (long) list of names, so you know which is the next 10? Since you will have the previous 10 still selected after hitting Ctrl+c to copy 10 names to clipboard, you would go back to the spreadsheet and hit down arrow to move to the next unselected cell.  You could have your script do that, or even do that and automatically select 10 more names (Shift+Down 10).  Or is it something in the dialog box?

Comment: I have created a separate post as this is now a new questions.@PGilm you can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49539410/8151407?sem=2

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to @PGilm

```
Gui, PasteGUI:Add, Text,, Please add the Names that you want to Process.
Counter := 0
Loop, parse, Clipboard, `n, `r
{
    x%A_Index% := A_LoopField
    Counter++
}
Counter--    
Loop, %Counter%  ;  Dynamic List length
Gui PasteGUI:Add, Edit, vButton%A_Index%, % x%A_Index%
Gui PasteGUI:Add, Button, x200 y270 w88 h26 vButton02 gGoCont Default, Continue
Gui PasteGUI:Add, Button,  x290 y270 w88 h26 vButton03 gGoQuit, Cancel  
Gui, PasteGUI:Show
}
Return
GoCont:
{
    Loop, %Counter%
    {
        CODE TO PROCESS MY EACH NAME
    }
    MsgBox Done!
    Gui Destroy
}
Return
GoQuit:  
    Gui Destroy 
Return
```

Lastly if I want to add a keyboard shortcut to work then I mapped in one where I put the below line at the top of the code

```
PasteIn:
{
```

And then close the bracket at the end of the code and then add the shortcut. (the below can be added to the bottom of the code to work) this uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

```
}

^v:: GoTo, PasteIn
```

Comment: Cool.  Let me try to help on the next issue:  showing which name is being processed . . .